# How to get all elements from querySelectorAll and use with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a block. When I click on plus, 4 subblocks are created.I have to add when I click on any of the subblocks plus buton (`rooms-guests-plus` class) , they increase from **0 to 5** and when click minus button (`rooms-guests-minus` class) decrease the same way.

```js
const room = document.querySelector('.room-guests-count');
const form = document.querySelector('.form-open');
const adultsChildren = document.querySelector('.adults-children');
const adultsChildrenWrapper = document.querySelector('.adults-children-wrapper');

const toggleRoom = () => {
  const addRoomButton = document.querySelector('#add-room');
  const removeRoomButton = document.querySelector('#remove-room');
  const countRoom = document.querySelector('.form-text');
 
  const addSection = () => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement("div"); 
    wrapper.className = "adults-children-wrapper"; 
    wrapper.innerHTML = adultsChildrenWrapper.innerHTML;                
    adultsChildren.appendChild(wrapper).querySelector(".room-count").innerText = countRoom.value;

  }
  const removeSection = () => {
    adultsChildren.lastChild.remove();
  }
  
  addRoomButton.onclick = () => {
    if(countRoom.value == 4) return;
    countRoom.value++;
    addSection();  
   }
  removeRoomButton.onclick = () => {
    if(countRoom.value == 1) return;
    countRoom.value--;
    removeSection();
  }
}
toggleRoom();
```

```css
body {
  background:#000;
}
/*ROOM GUESTS COUNT*/
.room-guests-count {
 width: 32.2%;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 4%;
 background: #fff;
 float: left;
 height: 66px;
 margin-right: 149px;
}
.form-open {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 85px;
 background-color: #fff;
 height: auto;
 width: 348px;
}

.form-open:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 right: 300px;
 top: -10px;
}
.room-guests-content {
 padding-top: 23px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.click_hidden_text {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 163px;
 top: 56px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.form-search {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
 
}
.form-item {
 padding: 10px 5px;
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
}
.edit-rooms {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.rooms-guests-plus, #add-room {
 float: right;
 color: #fff;
 background:#ccc;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 24px;
 top: -6px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.form-text {
 text-align: center;
 width: 6%;
 width: 20px !important;
 text-decoration: center;
 float: right;
 border:0;
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
 outline: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.textfield label {
 margin-right: 2.5px;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.children-1 label {
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.rooms-guests-minus, #remove-room {
 float: right;
 color: #fff;
 background:#e7e7e7;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 24px;
 top: -6px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor:auto;
}
.adults-children {
 clear: both;
}
.rooms-id {
 line-height: 40px;
 float: left;
 padding:5px 0 0 15px;
 color: #000;
}
.already-min {
 float: right;
 margin: -16px 0px 2px 6px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fff;
}
.already-min-search {
 float: right;
 margin: 5px 10px 5px 2px;
}
.adults-children-wrapper {
 clear: both;
}
.children-1 {
 padding: 10px 5px;
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
}
.edit-children {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.textfield {
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="room-guests-count">
    <div class="room-guests-content">
      Adult
      <span>2</span>
      , Child 
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-open">
  <div class="form-search">
    <div class="form-item">
      <label class="edit-rooms">Amount of number</label>
      <div id="add-room">+</div>
      <input class="form-text" value="1">
      <div id="remove-room">-</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="adults-children">
    <div class="adults-children-wrapper">
      <div class="rooms-id">Number <span class="room-count">1</span>:</div>
      <div class="already-min-search">
        <div class="children-1">
          <label for="edit-children">Child</label>
          <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
          <input type="text" value="0" class="form-text">
          <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="already-min">
        <div class="textfield">
          <label for="edit">Adult</label>
          <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
          <input type="text" value="0"  class="form-text">
          <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrote the `if` block in `addSection function` which the loop goes through all the elements (classes `.rooms-child-plus`) it works but the loop shows the error `Can not read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`.

```
if (adultsChildren.appendChild(wrapper)) {
    for(let i = 0;i < 4;i++){
      var roomsChildPlus = document.querySelectorAll(".rooms-child-plus");
      roomsChildPlus[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("hi");
      })
    }  
  }
```

### The question is why such an error is output and on the correct path I am? and HOW to take all the elements with `querySelectorAll` and then use the `addEventListener` as an array also in the same way

Comment: You have to parse the collection (NodeList) that `querySelectorAll` returns, and assign the event listener to each element individually.

Comment: @Archer yup thank u.Already did.I use Array.from  change nodelist to array but this didn't work.

Comment: ... or just spare yourself the hassle of having to loop through a set of elements to attach an event handler to each one individually altogether ... and use _event delegation_ instead.

Comment: I think this is simple flow --> `querySelectorAll` will return array then using for loop add event listener to each element.

Comment: I think you're getting a bit mixed up.  You create a for loop and then *inside that* you create a node list using `querySelectorAll()`, and then use the loop value to index it.  That makes no sense.  Create the node list then create the loop and access the node list elements inside that loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should loop through your `roomsChildPlus` instead of a hard coded length of 4.

```
var roomsChildPlus = document.querySelectorAll(".rooms-child-plus");

for(let j=0; j<roomsChildPlus.length; j++){
    roomsChildPlus[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("hi");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.rooms-child-plus').forEach(el => 
     el.addEventListener('click',()=> {
      alert('hi');
      //or your action
}))
```

There are a better way, to do this: use event delegation
[good example](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), you will have only one event listener on many DOM elements.

```
document.addEventListener('click',(event) => {
    if(event.target.classList.contain('.rooms-child-plus')){
        //do something :)
    }
})
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment - I only just noticed the ecma6 tag.

Comment: Thanks for your'e answer @simpleDmitry .Exactly I want to know how for each loop works in es6.

Comment: The forEach method allows to run a function for every element of the array, if look at my example: in each step will be next array element.

Comment: второй код от бога незнал что можно так O.o @simpleDmitry